# How can i remove the data of a row with a button click?

Tags: android, arraylist, row

After clicking a button my code creates a row in table with a TextView , an EditView and a delete button. The delete button is programmed to delete the row from the table (which successfully does) and the date from a list in Notes.class (which is the problem). To confirm this action i have a text view to count the list size with the dates and when i press the delete button nothing is changed. 
Sorry if this is a silly question but i am really new to Android :)

**The button handler**

```
 public void addButtonHandler(View view) {
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.subs_table);

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //get the date in string
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());

    //the TextView with the date
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(date);
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP , 18);

    //editText with the type
    final EditText et = new EditText(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(getPx(50), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(getPx(130),0,getPx(40),0);
    et.setLayoutParams(params);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SubsPREFERENCES , MODE_PRIVATE);   // get notes object
    Gson gsonN = new Gson();
    String jsonN = prefs.getString("DATES" , "");
    final Notes notes = gsonN.fromJson(jsonN , Notes.class);


    //button for deleting row
    ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams imageParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(50,70);
    imageParams.setMargins(5 ,0 ,0 ,0);
    imageButton.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    imageButton.setClickable(true);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            ViewGroup gradnparent = (ViewGroup) parent.getParent();
            gradnparent.removeView(parent);

            notes.delete(tv.getText().toString());  // this does not seem to work
            }
        }
    );

    // Adding views in row
    tr.addView(tv);
    tr.addView(et);
    tr.addView(imageButton);

    // Adding row in table
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            , TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



    //add info in note
    notes.addNote(date , et.getText().toString());

    // saving the changes in notes
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences(SubsPREFERENCES ,MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    String json1 = gsonN.toJson(notes);
    editor.putString("DATES" , json1);
    editor.apply();

    //display the number of objects in list
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(notes.getNum_dates()));
    }
```

**The notes class**

```
package com.uni.notes;



public class Notes {

private ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> type =new ArrayList<String>();

public Notes() {}

public int getNum_dates() {return list.size();}

public void addNote(String date ,String typeN) {

    list.add(date);
    type.add(typeN);
}
public String getDate (int pos){
    return list.get(pos);
}

public String getType (int pos) {return type.get(pos);}

public void delete (String thing) {
    for (String element : list){
        if (element.equals(thing) ){
           list.remove(element);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you debug this, does the delete method receive the input you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Just after

```
notes.delete(et.getText().toString());  // this does not seem to work
```

move your textview counting element update :

```
notes.delete(et.getText().toString());  // this does not seem to work
//display the number of objects in list
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(String.valueOf(notes.getNum_dates()));
```

This will update the counting `Textview` rigth after you clicked the delete button.

Comment: To be honest that was not my issue, but i figuered it out thanks to your advice